# minimal value in matrix / python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, min

i dont know how to find the index of minimum value in matrix, can you help me? i didnt find anythin on the internet about this

```
def printMatrix(matrix):
    for i in matrix:
       for j in i:
          print(j, end=' ')
       print()



m=[ [1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 1] , [5, 6, 8, 5, 6, 7] , [10, 12, 10, 12, 11, 11] , [8, 10, 5, 6, 8, 9] , [6, 5, 10, 12, 15, 19]]


printMatrix(m)
```

Comment: You'll want to flatten your matrix to a 1D vector/list and find the minimum value of that. You can use something like the built-in `min` function to find the minimum of a 1D list. Have a look around to find out how to flatten the list.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please review [ask] and provide a [mcve]. What do you expect as your output, and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

First, let's make a sample matrix:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)

mat = np.random.rand(3, 3)

print(mat)
```

Here's our matrix:

```
[[ 0.54340494  0.27836939  0.42451759]
 [ 0.84477613  0.00471886  0.12156912]
 [ 0.67074908  0.82585276  0.13670659]]
```

Then, we can set our initial "minimum" test value and the location of that value in the matrix:

```
min_val = mat[0][0]
min_idx = (0, 0)
```

Next, we can iterate through each row in the matrix, using `enumerate` to keep track of the index of the row we're in, and `np.argmin` to find the index of the smallest element in each row:

```
for idx, row in enumerate(mat):
    if min(row) < min_val:
        min_val = min(row)
        min_idx = (idx, np.argmin(row))

print(min_val, min_idx)
```

And, voilà! The minimum value and index is:

```
0.00471885619097 (1, 1)
```

Comment: Oops.  You beat me!

Comment: Or, use [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) - ```np.where(mat == mat.min())```

Answer (score 0):

This turns a 2D array into a 1D array, then finds the index of the minimum.

```
def maxIndex(matrix):
    matrix2 = []
    for a in range(len(matrix)):
        for b in range(len(matrix[a])):
            matrix2.append(matrix[a][b])
    val = -(10)^99
    index = 10^99
    for a in range(len(matrix2)):
        if matrix2[a]<val:
            val = matrix2[a]
            index = a
    return index
```

Before asking questions on this site about Python, you should first learn the basics of Python.  I suggest the book "Hello World!" by Carter and Warren Sande.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the first occurence:

```
>>> minimum = min(map(min, m))
>>> for i, thing in enumerate(m):
    try:
        j = thing.index(minimum)
        print('minimum is at m[{}][{}]'.format(i,j))
    except ValueError as e:
        pass

minimum is at m[0][0]
```

If you need the indices of all occurrences:

```
>>> minimum = min(map(min, m))
>>> for i, thing in enumerate(m):
    for j, x in enumerate(thing):
        if x == minimum:
            print('minimum is at m[{}][{}]'.format(i,j))

minimum is at m[0][0]
minimum is at m[0][1]
minimum is at m[0][5]
>>>
```